# where should we use commit(session), in try or finally?

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, try-catch

If I want to use commit(session) after successful execution of database operation, where its better to put it in try or in finally block ?
Here I used it in finally, should it be in try ?

```
public void delete( --- ) {
    Session session = init();
    try {
        ----
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        rollback(session);
        logger.error("delete failed", e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        commit(session);
        close(session);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be in `try`, for two reasons:

- You'll `commit` the session if some exception or error *other* than a `HibernateException`, and you almost certainly don't want to do that
- You'll call `commit` after calling `rollback`. I can't remember whether Hibernate allows you to do that (by silently ignoring the rollback) but at the very least it's ugly. Every session should *either* be committed *or* rolled back.

The normal solution here is to keep a separate `boolean` variable which is set when you've successfully commit, and check that in `finally`, rolling back if necessary:

```
boolean committed = false;
try {
    // Do stuff
    commit(session);
    committed = true;
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    logger.error("delete failed", e);
    throw e;
} finally {
    if (!committed) {
        rollback(session);
    }
    // TODO: This won't execute if rollback fails.
    // Check whether that's a problem.
    close(session);
}
```

Comment: I think that you should move the rollback inside the catch block (without committed flag) instead of using committed flag cause if the commit failed an exception would be thrown.

Comment: @AmjadAbdul-Ghani No, because then it wouldn't be rolled back if any other exception were thrown. And if the commit fails I'd at least expect it to be valid to then call rollback.

Comment: that is true ,if you did not handle the exceptions correctly , if you have ever seen spring transaction implementation the catch throwable >> the rethrow the error or the exception if needed ,both may work but I don't like  in humble opinion to put roll back statement  in the finally block,this my preference ,and thanks for your feedback

Comment: @Amjad: Whereas my preference is very definitely to use a finally block unless you're catching Throwable. It's far too easy to leak transactions otherwise, albeit temporarily. Finally blocks are precisely for the kind of cleanup we want here.

Answer (score 0):

It should be in `try`. `finally` will also called after `catch`.

Answer (score 0):

It should definitevly be placed in the try block. The finally block is usally only used to close any connection.

Comment: Well, the finally block should also be used for rollback in this case, IMO, if the session hasn't been committed. Otherwise any unhandled exceptions will end up leaking those sessions.

Answer (score 0):

you need to put it in try block otherwise you would not recognize any error and you could not rollback